# Prevent function from looking for variables in outer scopes

Tags: javascript

I want to do this because my project usually uses shortcut variables like the below:

```
(function() {
    var world = new World(),
        Event = world.Event,
        Guide = world.Guide;

    Event.add('updateUI', function() {
        // 1st: Correct, the value of 'this' refers to a world
        this.Guide.show('UI updated');
        // 2nd: Ok because 'world' was defined in outer scope
        world.Guide.show('UI updated');
        // 3rd: Ok because 'Guide' was defined in outer scope
        Guide.show('UI updated');
    });
})();
```

If I move `Event.add('updateUI', function() { ... });` to other file, only the first statement (`this.Guide.show`) works. How can I prevent this function from using the `world` or `Guide` variables of the outer scope so the second and third statements will throw errors from the beginning.

`use strict` is really close to this but it only prevent you from gaining access to the global object.

**Updated to make this question clearer:** The main question is: Are there any ways to prevent function from looking for variables in outer scopes? If there are no ways, please explain why because I think it's a reasonable need to do this.

Comment: You can't do what you're suggesting; the language simply works the way it works and that's that. Moving code inside a function into another file will as a matter of course take it out of that function and put it in a new context. You should describe what it is you're trying to achieve, because the question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This is called a closure.  It's one of the most useful features of Javascript; you can't disable it.

Comment: I was about to write that you want to go against the language and it is not a good idea to do so, but @Pointy wrote it much better :D

Comment: The only thing I'll add here is [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FNew_in_JavaScript%2F1.7#Block_scope_with_let_(Merge_into_let_Statement)) would let you do what you're trying to do here but it isn't widely supported yet.

Comment: Moving into another file is just an example. I think it would be really dangerous if you can't manage variables of the outer scope. For example `Guide` may be changed before it is used inside `Event.add` function.

Comment: I think `use strict` is much like an against the language feature. Why don't we have something like `use local variables only`?

Comment: `let` wouldn't fix this; it affects where the scope ends going "upwards", not downwards.  this is just how JS (along with many languages with closures) works.  if you don't want to risk closure complications, don't nest functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use shadowing. If you explicitly declare the variable inside the function (and not initialize it), the function will use this variable instead of a variable of the same name from an outer scope.

Example:

```
var outer = 'foo';

function isolated () {
  var outer;
  console.log(outer);
};

isolated(); // output undefined
```

This should cover your needs.

There is another way, but it's an ugly hack and probably won't work on some browsers (IE ?).

Here is an example:

```
var outer = 'foo';

function isolated () {
  console.log(outer);
};

var e = eval;
// will throw exception: 'outer' is not defined
console.log(e('('+isolated.toString()+')()'));
```

`eval` and `e` are not exactly the same. The 'true' eval has access to the whole scope, but if you copy it, then the javascript engines can optimize it by not making the outer scope available to the evaled code.

However: **Don't do that** !

- First: it relies on the fact that function.toString() will output the code of the function. This is not part of the specs and so is unreliable (works on v8 and spidermonkey though).
- Second: `eval` should be avoided, it makes debugging a nightmare (you don't have access to a useful stack trace), there are performance and security issues, and you end up very quickly with an awful code to maintain.

Comment: +1 but these will change my source code a lot. I'm currently ok with the fact that the language itself still doesn't allow you to isolate the scope of a function without any hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why would you like to do this, but using the short example:

```
(function(theFunk) {
    var world = new World(),
        Event = world.Event,
        Guide = world.Guide;

    Event.add('updateUI',theFunk);

})(function(){
        this.Guide.show('UI updated');  // 1st: depends on what you do with it
        world.Guide.show('UI updated'); // 2nd: will fail (depends on global)
        Guide.show('UI updated');       // 3rd: will fail (depends on global)
});
```